# QML. Can't close menu by press outside on android

Tags: android, qt, menu, qml, qtquick2

I want to close menu by press outside. It works fine on desktop. But can't work on android. Only press back button could close the menu .

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello Qt Quick")

    Component.onCompleted: menu.open()

    Menu {
        id: menu
        closePolicy: Popup.CloseOnPressOutside | Popup.CloseOnEscape
        MenuItem {
            text: "Test"
        }
    }
}
```

`Popup.CloseOnPressOutside` seems useless.

I use android 4.4.2. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

This bug slipped into Qt 5.7.0. It has been fixed in the upcoming Qt 5.7.1, being released shortly.

Comment: I have the same problem on MacOS. On windows it is working as expected. But I do use Qt 5.7.1

Comment: importing QtQuick.Controls 1.4 (instead of 2.0) fixed the problem for me.